# QSortFilterProxyModel is not working for me

Tags: c++, qt

I'm bit desperate at the moment. My model class with subclasses QStirngListModel when plugged in to a view works perfectly. When I plug qt's QSortFilterProxyModel between the model and the view I'm getting nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
    class Line_Counter : public QDialog, private Ui::Line_Counter
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    private:
        File_List_Model* model_;
        QSortFilterProxyModel* proxy_model_;
    };

Line_Counter::Line_Counter(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent), model_(new File_List_Model(this)),
    proxy_model_(new QSortFilterProxyModel(this))
{
    setupUi(this);

    setup_mvc_();
}

void Line_Counter::setup_mvc_()
{
    proxy_model_->setSourceModel(model_);
    listView->setModel(proxy_model_);//IF I plug model instead of proxy_model everything works
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try with proxy_model->setDynamicSortFilter(true)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld nope... are there any requirements for model to work correctly with this proxy model?

Comment: Does the [Qt Model Test](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Model_Test) report any errors with your model, or errors on the proxy model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `proxy_model_->sort(column);` for the proxy model to sort the data. If this doesn't help probably there is some problem with your File_List_Model. Can you show us some code?